# Select Max From 2 Tables Joined

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql as dbms and I have a problem when trying to show only latest data from 2 tables joined.
I have tbl_A

```
wid       date            val
-----------------------------
atjeh     11 Jan 2018     230
banda     22 Jan 2018     113
atjeh     20 Jan 2018     266
cirebon   21 Jan 2018     130
cirebon   09 Jan 2018     144
```

I have tbl_B

```
lid       wid
-------------
5500      atjeh
5501      cirebon
5502      banda
```

I want to join these tables like this:

```
wid          lid          date          val
-------------------------------------------
atjeh        5500        20 Jan 2018    266
banda        5502        22 Jan 2018    133
cirebon      5501        21 Jan 2018    130
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT tbl_A.wid, tbl_B.lid, MAX(tbl_A.date), tbl_A.val
FROM tbl_A
JOIN tbl_B ON tbl_B.wid = tbl_A.wid
GROUP BY tbl_B.witel
```

But the ouput only selecting latest date:

```
wid          lid          date          val
-------------------------------------------
atjeh        5500        20 Jan 2018    230 ---> should be 266
banda        5502        22 Jan 2018    133
cirebon      5501        21 Jan 2018    144 ---> should be 130
```

What should I do to fix this? Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a subquery which gets the latest `Date` for each `wid` then join the table to itself again to get all the columns you want.

```
SELECT  b.lid, b.wid,
        a.date, a.val
FROM    tbl_B b
        INNER JOIN tbl_a a
            ON b.wid = a.wid
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  wid, MAX(Date) AS Date
            FROM    tbl_a a
            GROUp   BY wid
        ) c
            ON c.wid = a.wid
                AND c.Date =  a.Date
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac2d9b/7).

Comment: Hello John, actually I have tried subquery before. But I put it in `where in` clause and did not find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have formed a query which will solve your issue. Instead of using group function  am using analytical function to solve this issue as performance will be better. I have used the same table and column names as you have used except the date column is changed to col_date.(Oracle is not allowing me to create a column with name "date" as it is a keyword). When you are using this query just change the "col_date" column to "date" and you are good to go.

Code:

```
    select 
wid,
lid,
col_date,
val from (
SELECT
    tbl_a.wid as wid,
    tbl_b.lid as lid,
    tbl_a.col_date as col_date,
    tbl_a.val val,
    max(tbl_A.col_date) over(partition by tbl_A.wid order by null) as max_date
FROM
     tbl_a
    JOIN  tbl_b ON tbl_b.wid = tbl_a.wid) where max_date=COL_DATE;
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !

```
SELECT    
              a.wid       AS wid  , 
              b.lid       AS lid  , 
              MAX(a.date) AS date ,
              MAX(a.val)  AS val
    FROM 
              tbl_A  a            ,
              tbl_B  b
    WHERE 
              a.wid = b.wid
    GROUP BY 
              a.wid
```